# Bundle is null in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I create the bundle in my Activity with

```
ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putInt("i", 0);
            Log.i("Bundle", String.valueOf(bundle.getInt("i")));

            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

And I get the arguments in my Fragment with

```
 Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

        if (bundle != null) {

            myInt = bundle.getInt("i", -1);

        }
```

But it says that my bundle is null. Any idea why?

Comment: in what location are you trying to read the arguments? (method name)

Comment: I'm trying to read them in onCreateView @LenaBru

Comment: Try deleting ```this```, and only use ```getArguments();```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately still null @PrinceAli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I initially had my bundle variable declared outside the onCreateView function. Once I moved it inside, it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the fragment you want to read the arguments was created from the provided code block #1? Your code is correct, there is nothing wrong so it must work. (as long as the arguments are accessed after onCreate, which they are)

Comment: Not 100% sure how would I find out? It's my first time working with fragments. The name of the fragment is ListFragment if that's what I'm looking for

Comment: add full code. only this sample isn't enough to help you